# What to do to avoid VBA function executed in the wrong work book

Tags: excel, vba

I have several excel files that have timer and macros executing. But a big problem is when workbook A's macro is called, while workbook B is active. The macro is executed in the wrong book and failed.

1. Do I need to put windows().active at the beginning of every function?
2. If I have different modules how do I pass this workbook name to all of them?
3. This seems excessive and not right. Is there any good solution to this problem?

Looking forward to your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track with this

> 2.If I have different modules how do I pass this workbook name to all of them

I assume that your macro is using the `ActiveWorkbook` property, or just using Worksheet properties like `Range` without qualifying them?

Instead of using `ActiveWorkbook` use `ThisWorkbook`. Instead of using `Range` use `ThisWoorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range` and so forth. Otherwise the macro will assume that the active worksheet is the one you want.

```
Sub MyMacro
  Range("A1").Text = "Test"
End Sub
```

Try

```
Sub MyMacro(ByVal oWorksheet as Worksheet)
  oWorksheet.Range("A1").Text = "Test"
End Sub
```

Then pass the worksheet object as a parameter.

You may also find the `ThisWorkbook` object useful - it is the workbook the macro resides in, or the `Application.Caller` object, which is the object calling the current macro, for example the Range object if it is a cell formula, or presumably the timer object in your case.

Comment: @Ben, I usually use nothing else but Range, Cells, sometimes i use Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate to switch between sheets to do copy and paste.

Comment: @Ben, Now after seeing your comments, I feel that I should add oWrokSheet identifier in front of every Range, Cell, Sheet like in your example. But I still have a question regarding how to pass this oWrokSheet to every module. Because I dont want to change the function signature. How can I efficiently do that?

Comment: @Johnyy, Your problem is that you want to allow the function to call the "right" worksheet, but allow the user to use a different one at the same time. So you either need a magic function `GetRightWorkbook` or change the function signature. Have you tried `Application.Caller` that might be magic enough? If it is being called from a timer, you should be able to find the worksheet where the timer resides using the `Parent` property?

Comment: Also see Doc Brown's suggestion which may be easier.

Comment: @Ben, if I do this "Sub MyMacro(ByVal oWorksheet as Worksheet)" will I be able to call a function in workbook B from workbook A?

Comment: Yes, I believe you can do that no problem you just need to pass in the correct worksheet object. You may have to save the functions as an AddIn though, I am not sure about that.

Answer (score 2):

If your macros behave the way you described it, they probably depend explicitly or implicitly on

```
ActiveWorkbook
```

or

```
 ActiveSheet
```

Those kind of dependencies should be avoided, if possible. The macro recorder produces such code, you should change it immediately whenever you have recorded a macro.

For example, if you have some code like

```
s = Range("A1").Value
```

Excel implicitly changes that to

```
s = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value
```

One can avoid that by accessing all cells, ranges, workbook parts etc. by explicitly using the right sheet or workbook object:

```
Dim sh as Worksheet
Set sh = .... ' Initialize sh the first time where the sheet is created or loaded

'later on:

s = sh.Range("A1").Value
```

By using a parameters of the form

```
sh as Worksheet, wb as workbook
```

for your subs and functions, you can pass the right sheet and workbook between modules, which answers your second question. And if you need access to the workbook where your macro resides, use `ThisWorkbook`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go one further... make sure your code doesn't have 
Selection
or 
ActiveCell

objects within them. You would need to rewrite these using the Range object.