# Workbooks.Open populates "source" rather than "target" file

Tags: vba, excel

I have tried the below, and many others not noted, with limited success.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx

[Workbooks.Open Method in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944068/workbooks-open-method-in-vba)

My situation is this:  I have a weekly file, produced from our ERP system, that populates limited information.  I have a macro recorded (yes, I know...) to automatically populate the other data I need, linked from another source, but the macro always requests that I open the "source" workbook before the data can populate.  I wanted to use the "Open.Workbooks" expression to open the workbook (read only & do not update links) so I would not have to "drill down" into the source workbook every time I run the macro.

I found the string that will open the workbook as a read-only file, and does not update links.  I have tested it as a stand-alone, and it works like a charm:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="SourceFile.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=False
```

The problem I am having is when I combine this small subroutine with my other macro, the data that is supposed to populate in the "target" file actually populates in the "source" file.  I need to open the "source" document, then somehow activate the "target" workbook so that the data population occurs in the "target" workbook, not the "source"

I have seen snippets of code that are relevant to setting the active workbook to the "target" workbook after the "open.workbooks" expression is used, but I do not know how to implement them.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be helpful to show the code that's not working.

Comment: Please post the code snippet to better understand why the source is populating instead of the target workbook

Comment: possible duplicate of [What to do to avoid VBA function executed in the wrong work book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260005/what-to-do-to-avoid-vba-function-executed-in-the-wrong-work-book)

Answer (score 1):

```
dim wbsource as workbook
dim wbtarget as workbook

set wbsource = activeworkbook
set wbtarget = Workbooks.Open Filename:="SourceFile.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=False

'do your code here
```

Set two different workbook objects.